# Reading tile package file(.tpk) in ArcObject C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.4, arcobjects, tile-package

I wish to read and show some tile package file using ArcObject C# 10.x.

However, I failed to find how to read an tile package file on My Application using ArcObject C#.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I've never tried to "read" a tile package, I always thought they were a way of delivering data in a compressed format, so you need to uncompress them or "un-pack" them, probably easiest calling the geoprocessor tool?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought that ArcObject SDK can read the tile package in some document(for example, [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/webapps.esri.com/esri-proceedings/devsummit12/papers/developing_.net_applications_for_arcgis_engine.pdf)). According to this document, does it mean that I should use a data of un-packed the tile package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar with the `IPackageFile` object. The [unpack](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ipackagefile_unpack.htm) method should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From the [answer of @Dowlers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192329/115), I found solution to use .tpk file on ArcObjects.

```c#
public static ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer GetLayerFromTilePackage(string path)
{
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) == false)
    return null;

  //var layer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.RasterLayerClass();
  //layer.CreateFromFilePath(path);
  string unpackPath = "";

  IPackageFile pkFile = new PackageFileClass();
  pkFile.Unpack(path, ref unpackPath);

  // Create a new GxLayer
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxLayer gxLayer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxLayerClass();

  ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxFile gxFile = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxFile)gxLayer; //Explicit Cast

  // Set the path for where the layerfile is located on disk
  gxFile.Path = unpackPath + "\\Layers.lyr";
  if (gxLayer.Layer == null)
  {
    gxFile.Path = unpackPath + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + ".lyr";
  }

  return gxLayer.Layer;
}
```